# How to se the cscope database directory in emacs?

Tags: emacs, cscope

I use cscope with emacs, and it works well, but it creates cscope.out and cscope.files in the root directory.
My project is configure so that only the "/private" directory is ignored by SVN.

How can I tell cscope to put its files in "/myproject/private" rather than "/myproject"?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xcscope) there is no such setting (or at least I cannot find it). If SVN is what concerns you can just ignore the cscope files on their own.